# R sub setting based on column names and calculating p values

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, subset

I have this data frame as seen below in my code. What I want to do is print  the 5 proteins with most significant difference between sample1 (Any with sample 1 in, can be any letter after) and sample 2 (Any with sample 2 in, can be any letter after). The p value needs to be calculated from a wilcoxon test.

I want to conduct a wilcoxon non-parametric test on these data to compute a p value which I then want to use to order the proteins, based on this value.
I am unsure how I can subset the data based on sample name, matching up any with 1 or 2 in regardless of the letter that follows, as long as the number is the same. I am not sure where to begin the code and how to even subset the data correctly for sample 1 together and then sample 2.

To make things clearer, I want to conduct a wilcoxon test on all of samples 1 and 2 separately. Then use this p value to print of the top 5 proteins most significantly different from each other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
protein<-c("COX4", "LJK2", "JJ2", "HK1", "3DFG", "JE3","LOP2","PQE8")
    sample1a<-c(2.01, 1.58, 1.49,2.09, 2.11, 1.54, 1.39, 1.49)
    sample1b<-c(2.04, 1.57, 1.47,2.04, 2.10, 1.51, 1.40, 1.49)
    sample2a<-c(2.07, 1.52, 1.59,2.19, 1.41, 1.51, 1.36, 1.41)
    sample2b<-c(2.01, 1.48, 1.43,2.04, 2.01, 1.44, 1.49, 1.53)
    sample3a<-c(2.11, 1.48, 1.49,2.09, 2.11, 1.54, 1.39, 1.48)
    sample3b<-c(2:21, 1.38, 1.29,2.39, 2.07, 1.59, 1.29, 1.38)


df<-data.frame(protein,sample1a,sample1b,sample2a,sample2b, sample3a, sample3b)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your posted data is not right, in vector `sample3b` you have values with `:` instead of a decimal point. Besides, why characters?
You can conduct all pair-wise columns tests with the following.

```
# First convert to numeric
df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df[-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))

# Now define a function to be applied to pairs of columns
fun <- function(x, y) wilcox.test(x, y, exact = FALSE)$p.value
# apply the function above
result <- sapply(df2, function(x) sapply(df2[-1], fun, x))

any(result < 0.05)    # no p-value is significant
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to R and forgot about not needing to make characters, thanks for the help.